# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, sharing

I have a problem when created a new app in facebook and use it for sharing in Titanium with the Facebook Module , i get this error :

```
Error: HTTP status code: 403
[ERROR] :  FB: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

So if i used my old (other) appid with the same code and and the same config in facebook apps section it works fine.

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream', 'read_stream'];

if(!fb.loggedIn) {
    fb.authorize();
} 

var data = {
    message: messageToShare,
    picture: blobImageToShare
};

fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/photos', data, "POST", function(e){
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info("FB: Success! Shared to FB: " + e.result);
    } 
    else {
        if (e.error) {
           Ti.API.error('FB: '+ e.error);
        } 
        else {
            Ti.API.error("FB: Unkown result sharing");
        }
    }
});
```

Titanium version : 3.3.0 
Titanium SDK 3.3.0 
Platform & version : iOS >=6 
Device: iOS simulator, iPhone 4 & 5.
any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the Facebook authorization completes before attempting to do a Graph query.

```
fb.authorize();

fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug('Returned from Facebook.');

    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.debug('Authorized with Facebook, yeeey!');
        // Query Graph now that we're authorized...
    }
    else if (e.error) {
        Ti.API.debug('Error logging in with Facebook: ' + e.error);
    }
    else if (e.cancelled) {
        Ti.API.debug('Cancelled logging in with Facebook.');
    }
    else {
        Ti.API.debug('Something else. May actually be logged out.');
    }
});
```

Also, make sure you define your Facebook appid in your *tiapp.xml* file:

```
<property name="ti.facebook.appid">xxxxxxxxxxxx</property>
```

Comment: Thank you kip for replies but my code it works fine with old appi not for a new appid and i'm sure that a graph query after Facebook authorization.